# OpenMP in Fortran in R - program seems to hang for no reason?

Tags: r, fortran, openmp

I have a program in R which calls a couple of Fortran routines, which are openMP-enabled. There are two Fortran routines `sub_1` and `sub_2`. The first one is called twice in an R function, while the second is called once. Both routines are almost identical except for a few minor things. I call the first routine, then the second, then the first again. However, if I have both of them openMP-enabled, the function stops doing anything (doesn't have an error or stop execution, just sits there) when it gets to the second time it uses the first fortran routine.

If I disable the openMP in `sub_1` then everything runs fine. If I instead disable the openMP in `sub_2`, then it again hangs in the same fashion on the second usage of `sub_1`. This is odd because it obviously gets through the first usage fine.

I thought it may be to do with the threads not closing properly or something (I don't know too much about openMP). However, another oddity is that the R function that calls these three routines is being called four times, and if I only enable openMP in `sub_2`, then this works fine (ie. the second, third etc. call to `sub_2` doesn't hang). I just have no idea why it would do this! For reference, this is the code for `sub_1`:

```
subroutine correlation_dd_rad(s_bins,min_s,end_s,n,pos1,dd,r)   
!!! INTENT IN !!!!!!!!
integer             :: s_bins       !Number of separation bins
integer             :: N            !Number of objects
real(8)             :: pos1(3,N)    !Cartesian Positions of particles
real(8)             :: min_s        !The smallest separation calculated.
real(8)             :: end_s        !The largest separation calculated.
real(8)             :: r(N)         !The radii of each particle (ascending)
!!! INTENT OUT !!!!!!!
real(8)             :: dd(N,s_bins)         !The binned data.

!!! LOCAL !!!!!!!!!!!!
integer             :: i,j      !Iterators
integer             :: bin
real(8)             :: d            !Distance between particles.
real(8)             :: dr,mins,ends
real(8),parameter   :: pi = 3.14159653589

integer             :: counter
dd(:,:) = 0.d0

dr = (end_s-min_s)/s_bins

!Perform the separation binning
mins = min_s**2
ends = end_s**2

counter = 1000
!$OMP parallel do private(d,bin,j)
do i=1,N
    !$omp critical (count_it)
        counter = counter - 1
    !$omp end critical (count_it)
    if(counter==0)then
        counter = 1000
        write(*,*) "Another Thousand"
    end if
    do j=i+1,N
        if(r(j)-r(i) .GT. end_s)then
            exit
        end if

        d=(pos1(1,j)-pos1(1,i))**2+&
            &(pos1(2,j)-pos1(2,i))**2+&
            &(pos1(3,j)-pos1(3,i))**2
        if(d.LT.ends .AND. d.GT.mins)then
            d = Sqrt(d)
            bin = Floor((d-min_s)/dr)+1
            dd(i,bin) = dd(i,bin)+1.d0
            dd(j,bin) = dd(j,bin)+1.d0
        end if
    end do
end do
!$OMP end parallel do
write(*,*) "done"
end subroutine
```

Does anyone have any clue why this would happen??

Cheers.

I'll add in the smallest example that I can think of that does reproduce the problem (by the way, this must be an R problem - a small example of the type that I present here but written in fortran works fine). So I have the above code and the following code in fortran, compiled to the shared object `correlate.so`:

```
subroutine correlation_dr_rad(s_bins,min_s,end_s,n,pos1,n2,pos2,dd,r1,r2)

!!! INTENT IN !!!!!!!!
integer             :: s_bins       !Number of separation bins
integer             :: N            !Number of objects
integer             :: n2
real(8)             :: pos1(3,N)    !Cartesian Positions of particles
real(8)             :: pos2(3,n2)   !random particles
real(8)             :: end_s        !The largest separation calculated.
real(8)             :: min_s        !The smallest separation
real(8)             :: r1(N),r2(N2) !The radii of particles (ascending)

!!! INTENT OUT !!!!!!!
real(8)             :: dd(N,s_bins)         !The binned data.

!!! LOCAL !!!!!!!!!!!!
integer             :: i,j      !Iterators
integer             :: bin
real(8)             :: d            !Distance between particles.
real(8)             :: dr,mins,ends
real(8),parameter   :: pi = 3.14159653589

integer             :: counter
dd(:,:) = 0.d0

dr = (end_s-min_s)/s_bins

!Perform the separation binning

mins = min_s**2
ends = end_s**2

write(*,*) "Got just before parallel dr"
counter = 1000
!$OMP parallel do private(d,bin,j)
do i=1,N
    !$OMP critical (count)
            counter = counter - 1
        !$OMP end critical (count)
            if(counter==0)then
                write(*,*) "Another thousand"
                counter = 1000
            end if
    do j=1,N2


        if(r2(j)-r1(i) .GT. end_s)then
            exit
        end if
        d=(pos1(1,j)-pos2(1,i))**2+&
            &(pos1(2,j)-pos2(2,i))**2+&
            &(pos1(3,j)-pos2(3,i))**2
        if(d.GT.mins .AND. d.LT.ends)then
            d = Sqrt(d)
            bin = Floor((d-min_s)/dr)+1
            dd(i,bin) = dd(i,bin)+1.d0
        end if
    end do
end do
!$OMP end parallel do

write(*,*) "Done"
end subroutine
```

Then in R, I have the following functions - the first two just wrap the above fortran code. The third calls it in a similar way to my actual code:

```
correlate_dd_rad = function(pos,r,min_r,end_r,bins){
  #A wrapper for the fortran routine of the same name.
  dyn.load('correlate.so')
  out = .Fortran('correlation_dd_rad',
             s_bins = as.integer(bins),
             min_s = as.double(min_r),
             end_s = as.double(end_r),
             n = as.integer(length(r)),
             pos = as.double(t(pos)),
             dd = matrix(0,length(r),bins), #The output matrix.
             r = as.double(r))

  dyn.unload('correlate.so')
  return(out$dd)
}

correlate_dr_rad = function(pos1,r1,pos2,r2,min_r,end_r,bins){
  #A wrapper for the fortran routine of the same name
  N = length(r1)
  N2 = length(r2)
  dyn.load('correlate.so')

  out = .Fortran('correlation_dr_rad',
             s_bins = as.integer(bins),
             min_s = as.double(min_r),
             end_s = as.double(end_r),
             n = N,
             pos1 = as.double(t(pos1)),
             n2 = N2,
             pos2 = as.double(t(pos2)),
             dr = matrix(0,nrow=N,ncol=bins),
             r1 = as.double(r1),
             r2 = as.double(r2))

  dyn.unload('correlate.so')
  return(out$dr)
}

the_calculation = function(){

  #Generate some data to use
  pos1 = matrix(rnorm(30000),10000,3)
  pos2 = matrix(rnorm(30000),10000,3)

  #Find the radii
  r1 = sqrt(pos1[,1]^2 + pos1[,2]^2+pos1[,3]^2)
  r2 = sqrt(pos2[,1]^2 + pos2[,2]^2+pos2[,3]^2)

  #usually sort them but it doesn't matter here.

  #Now call the functions
  print("Calculating the data-data pairs")
  dd = correlate_dd_rad(pos=pos1,r=r1,min_r=0.001,end_r=0.8,bins=15)

  print("Calculating the data-random pairs")
  dr = correlate_dr_rad(pos1,r1,pos2,r2,min_r=0.001,end_r=0.8,bins=15)

  print("Calculating the random-random pairs")
  rr = correlate_dd_rad(pos=pos2,r=r2,min_r=0.001,end_r=0.8,bins=15)

  #Now we would do something with it but I don't care in this example.
  print("Done")
}
```

Running this I get the output:

```
 [1] "Calculating the data-data pairs"
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  Another Thousand
  done
 [1] "Calculating the data-random pairs"
  Got just before parallel dr
  Another thousand
  Another thousand
```

And then it just sits there... Actually, running it a few times has shown that it changes where it hangs each time. Sometimes it gets most of the way through the second call to `correlate_dd_rad` and others it only gets halfway through the call to `correlate_dr_rad`.

Comment: Please provide a small example which reproduces your problem. Especially with this kind of parallel processing it is hard to spot what is going wrong when we cannot run the code ourselves.

Comment: Edited my post to contain a simple program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, but it is indeed a bug. In subroutine `correlation_dd_rad` when you intended to close the parallel region, you actually put a comment. To be more clear the line that reads:

```
 !OMP end parallel do
```

should be converted to:

```
 !$OMP end parallel do
```

As side notes:

1. you don't need to `use omp_lib` if you don't call the library functions
2. you can use the `atomic` construct (see [section 2.8.5](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf) of the latest OpenMP specifications) to access a specific storage location atomically, instead of a `critical` construct
3. always give a name to `critical` constructs as (section 2.8.2 of the specifications)

> All **critical** constructs without a name are considered to have the same unspecified name.

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful response. I have changed the code accordingly (I named the critical sections, rather than changing them to atomic - is there a benefit to them being atomic?). I really thought this would fix it. But it still hangs at random places (either the first call to `correlate_dr_rad` or the second call to `correlate_dd_rad`.

Comment: Just ran it again with the same code and it seemed to do all the calculations but then before finishing gave an `abort trap: 6` error.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but when I turn off openMP in the `correlate_dd_rad` routines and run it in R, the program finishes fine. However, after its done and I try to type something else in the console, gibberish just comes up (ie. `^[[A` when I push the up arrow). It also says that R is using 100% of CPU even though it shouldn't be doing anything... does that sound like the fortran threads are still going nuts behind the scenes?

Comment: For some reason I tried it on a server here at work which has ifort. It worked. Not sure why... but I ticked this response because it definitely was an error - probably the main one I had. I also added the `if... write(*,*) "Another Thousand" ...end if` to the critical section which may have helped.

Comment: Glad the response was of use. You are right saying that the `if` statement should go into the critical as there would be otherwise a race condition when assigning `counter`